# Sending POST request from VueJS to PHP

Tags: php, vue.js, post, axios

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Origin, Accept, X-Requested-Wurh, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers ");

$curl = curl_init($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);

$data = curl_exec($curl);

if($data===false){
    var_dump(curl_error($curl));
} else {
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
    var_dump($data);
}
curl_close($curl); ?>
```

```js
updateCilent(){
      let data = {"name":"john","lastname":"doe"};
      axios
      .post('http://127.0.0.1/devphp/projet/action.php',
      data
      )
      .then(console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    },
```

I've tried to send a post request from Vue JS to php ! I want to retrieve the value of 'codecli' from my "index.js" ([index.js Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMN1Z.png)) file but I can't! The post request works correctly when I do console.log the data ([data console.log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mY8u.png)) but I receive nothing in my php file ([php code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WzrM.png))! this is what it looks like on the browser ([empty string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6zGm.png))! Someone can help me ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change php to:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Origin, Accept, X-Requested-Wurh, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers ");

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```